# is this the correct setup for unicorn on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I ran into an issue on heroku yesterday where my redis connection was getting stale (heroku + postgres + sidekiq). The exact error was:

```
Re: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
```

I wasn't sure what that meant so I looked it up and found this SOF question: [Heroku + Sidekiq: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UnableToSend: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802233/heroku-sidekiq-activerecordstatementinvalid-pgunabletosend-ssl-syscall)

I implemented the following in my sidekiq.rb initializer:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  pool_size = Sidekiq.options[:concurrency] + 2

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = pool_size
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

however, then heroku told me the reason for the error was on their end, they took my DB down for maintenance...very confusing.

So upon reading heroku docs, I saw i needed this to setup unicorn server:

unicorn.rb:

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

my question is, is this the right setup for my system? isn't there a conflict since i call ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection twice?